# postfix virtual_mailbox_maps deliver to two maildirs

Tags: postfix

I have postfix with configuration like this:

### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps  =   hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains =   /etc/postfix/vdomains
virtual_mailbox_base    =   /VMAIL
virtual_mailbox_maps    =   hash:/etc/postfix/vusers
virtual_minimum_uid =   1000
virtual_uid_maps    =   static:5000
virtual_gid_maps    =   static:5000
```

### /etc/postfix/vusers

```
boss@domain.com         domain.com/boss/
editor@domain.com       domain.com/editor/
novini@domain.com       domain.com/novini/
```

### /etc/postfix/virtual

```
postmaster@domain.com   boss@domain.com
```

It currently works ok, but I want when:

Someone sent mail to `editor@domain.com`, the email to be stored in both `domain.com/editor/` and `domain.com/novini/`. Also I want a copy of the email to be forward to person personal email - `editor@webmail.com`

Same if someone sent to `novini@domain.com`, the email to be stored in both `domain.com/editor/` and `domain.com/novini/`. In this case I do not want any email to be sent to  `editor@webmail.com`

How is easier way to set up this with `virtual_mailbox_maps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following in `virtual`

### /etc/postfix/virtual

```
postmaster@domain.com   boss@domain.com
editor@domain.bg        novini@domain.bg, editor@domain.bg, boss@domain.bg, user@webmail.com
novini@domain.bg        novini@domain.bg, editor@domain.bg, boss@domain.bg, user@webmail.com
```

postfix is smart, so it does not "loop".